# Run a fallback script when liquibase script fails in gradle

Tags: liquibase, fallback

I'm using Liquibase with gradle in order to apply database changes.
I have three activities in runList:
runList='stop_job, execute_changes, start_job'

It works fine in case that I don't have any exception, but if something fails on the second step (execute_changes) it stops there and does not execute "start_job" activity.

Is it possible to introduce something like a fallback activity or "finally" block?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [failOnError:false](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html). It defines whether the migration will fail if an error occurs while executing the changeset. Default value is true.

Comment: Hi Adeel,
Thanks for your comment!
 failOnError is a good option, but then the Liquibase process will be marked as SUCCESSFUL and it is easy to miss some important information.

Comment: Are you using Oracle? If so, you can look into runWith:sqlplus and then use sqlplus command, e.g., WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE so that the operation carries on despite errors. Not sure how to do this with other databases.